# Calculate against mysql trigger

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

Right now I am facing some issues in mysql trigger as I am very new at it.

I have two tables named `app_form` and and `venue_master`. The problem is when I insert into table `app_form`, I have to calculate `venue` from the `venue_master` table and update `app_form` with that value.

Now during calculation of venue, I have to fetch data from venue master and put it in `while` loop (like `mysql_query` and `mysql_fetch_assoc` concept) and compare some values and then finally getting venue.

So what will be the syntax? And what be the logic?

Please help...

After a lot of research, I have written sort of code. Please check is that ok or not. Where do I have problems in logic?

```html
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS before_form_insert $$
CREATE TRIGGER before_form_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON `app_form`
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

LOCK TABLES app_form WRITE;
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE vId, vCap, cnt, cntTotal, admit_no, venue, venueName INT;
DECLARE vName, r1, r2, roll VARCHAR(250);
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT `venue_id` , `venue_capacity` FROM venue_master ORDER BY venue_id ASC;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

OPEN cur1;

read_loop: LOOP
FETCH cur1 INTO vId, vCap;
IF done THEN
LEAVE read_loop;
END IF;
SET cnt = ( SELECT count(*) FROM app_form WHERE status=1 AND venuename=vId );
IF cnt < vCap THEN
SET cntTotal = ( SELECT count(*) FROM app_form WHERE status=1 );
SET admit_no = (cntTotal + 1);
SELECT venue_name INTO vName FROM venue_master WHERE venue_id = vId;
SET venue = vId;
SET venueName = vName;
SET r1=UPPER(SUBSTRING(vName,1,4));
SET r2=LPAD(admit_no, 5, 0);
SET roll=CONCAT(r1,'2015',r2);
LEAVE read_loop;
END IF;
END LOOP;

CLOSE cur1;

SET NEW.admit_no=admit_no, NEW.roll_no=roll, NEW.venuename=venue, NEW.venue_name=venueName;

UNLOCK TABLES;

END $$;
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just need to count how many venue does your table contain . you can just add count query and insert the $value into ur app_form value.

```
$value =  mysql_query('select count from venue') ; 


or if you need to get some value from the venue 

$query =  mysql_query('select *  count from venue') ; 

while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($query )){

   if($r['somevalue'] = $othervalue) {
      //perform your operation // eg insert ur app-form data 
   }

}
```

i just told you the logic syntax can be wrong so please fix